# Android installation process from downloaded android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

I have android sdk, I want to integrate this with eclipse Helio.  From developer site, i need to do from downloading sdk again. Can any one tell the procedure to intall.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It works like any thing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to download Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin for your Eclipse. See http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html.

Also, Here is link to a step by step tutorial that you may find useful:
http://blog.kerul.net/2011/06/eclipse-helios-android-development.html

Hope that helps. :)